# Derivations for two formulae for obtaining optimal dual variable values from the optimal primal tableau

Tags: simplex, duality, global-optimality, dual-simplex, dual

We're being taught Industrial Engineering and Operations Research for the first time this semester. Referring to the book by Hamdy A. Taha, I noticed the mention of two formulae for swiftly obtaining the dual variable optimal solutions from the primal optimal tableau:

> **Method 1.** $${\text{Optimal value of}\\dual\text{ variable }y_i}\quad=\quad{{\text{Optimal primal }z\text{-coefficient of }\\starting\text{ basic variable }x_i}\quad+\quad{Original\text{ objective}\\\text{coefficient of }x_i}}$$ **Method 2.** $${\text{Optimal values}\\\text{of }dual\text{ variables}}\quad=\quad{\text{Row vector of }original\\\text{objective coefficients of}\\\text{optimal }primal\text{ basic}\\\text{variables}}\quad\times\quad{\text{Optimal }primal\text{ inverse}}$$

Does anyone have an intuitive explanation from how these are derived?

Comment: Welcome to OR SE. By "intuitive" do you mean an outline of the logic behind a derivation, or do you mean something expressed in terms of "costs" (or "profits") and marginal costs or profits (i.e., something in economic terms)?

Comment: To calculate what you looking for Based on the simplex method (algebra expressions), you can use $z_j - c_j = c_bB^{-1}a_j - c_j$ to figure out objective function row in each iterate in the tableau. Also, this [link](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~sahmed/isye3133b/simplex) would be useful.

Comment: @prubin no sorry, we're not learning this strictly from an econ perspective. I was looking for the logic behind the derivation. Thanks, and sorry for the late response! Just in case, I'm from a Mechanical Engineering undergraduate here.

Comment: @A.Omidi that link was super helpful! Thank you!